# Replacing a member of a replica set with the same host name

Tags: replication, mongodb

I am replacing a member of a replica set (the new member has a different IP address).

What I am looking to do is as follows:

- RSYNC the data directory of the existing secondary node to the new node.
- Stop the existing node.
- Map the existing hostname to the IP of the new node.
- Start MongoDB on this new node with the replica set.

Mongo Version 3.2 and storage engine MMapV1

it is 3 member replica set.

Primary
Secondary
Arbiter
My plan is to first replace arbiter with a new secondary node then. Do the procedure with on existing secondary node to replace this also.

Could someone please verify if the above steps make sense?

Comment: What version of MongoDB and (if 3.0+, what storage engine) are you using? In general you should not copy or `rsync` files from a running deployment as this is likely to introduce data inconsistency if files are being written to. You would be much safer reversing your first two steps: stop the existing secondary and then rsync the data files.

Comment: @Stennie i have updated the question. My query is if i do not rsync and replace arbiter first with new machine with same host name will it rsync data from primary. Then i can go ahead with secondary with same procedure.

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Are you referring to [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) (the command line file-copying tool) or MongoDB replication [initial sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#initial-sync)? Are you replacing one member of the replica set or two (an arbiter and/or secondary)? Per my original comment, you should not use `rsync` on a running deployment. Initial sync is the normal process where you would `rs.add()` a new secondary. You cannot convert an arbiter into a secondary, as arbiters do not have any data.

Comment: @Stennie i am not replacing Arbiter to secondary. I am removing it and adding fully data node. As per your suggestion i will use initial sync only as it will give more balanced accuracy for data. Could you please ass this as Answer so that i will close it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you want if you first rs.add() the new secondary, and when it's done you rs.remove() the arbiter.

There will be a brief period of thime with 4 nodes, howerever.